# Getting wrong location latitude and longitude based on address in php

Tags: php, google-maps

Finding the location latitude and longitude based on street, city, state, zip using Google map. I'm taking the address from Google map and trying to find latitude and longitude. But my code always gives wrong place location.

Code:-

```
<?php

$con = mysql_connect("localhost","location","password");
if (!$con) {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}

$street =$_REQUEST[street];
$city   =$_REQUEST[city];
$state  =$_REQUEST[state];
$zip    =$_REQUEST[zip];
$result=null;

mysql_select_db("map", $con);

$address = $street . ', &nbsp;' . $city . ', &nbsp;' . $state. ', &nbsp;' . $zip; // Google HQ
$prepAddr = str_replace(' ','+',$address);

$geocode=file_get_contents('http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address='.$prepAddr.'&sensor=false');

$output= json_decode($geocode);

$lat  = $output->results[0]->geometry->location->lat;
$long = $output->results[0]->geometry->location->lng;

if($lat==0.0000 && $long==0.0000){
$result="ERROR";
}else{

$sql="INSERT INTO markers (name, address, lat, lng) VALUES ('".$street."', '".$city.", " .$state ."', '".$lat."', '".$long."')";
$result="SUCCESS";
}

if (!mysql_query($sql,$con)) {
  echo $result;
} else {
  echo $result;
}
```

Comment: Can you post an example of what you input and put into the database and possibly Google's response from the call?

Comment: @Jonathon examle like:- street->Synergy Web Tech Pvt. Ltd.
701, Goyal Trade Center
Shantivan Complex Colony, city-> Borivali East
Mumbai, state-> Maharashtra zip-> 400066.. this address is taken from google map .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try replacing these lines

```
$address = $street . ', &nbsp;' . $city . ', &nbsp;' . $state. ', &nbsp;' . $zip; // Google HQ
$prepAddr = str_replace(' ','+',$address);
```

Replace

```
$address = $street . '+' . $city . '+' . $state. '+' . $zip; 
$prepAddr = urlencode($address);
```

Comment: if you urlencode the string, you shouldn't concat with plus in between, just use a space